# Making a simple change function for a database app C#

Tags: c#, arrays, database, cmd

Sorry if this is an ultra beginner question but, I need to be able to change all field values except the item number by giving its item number not array index. I already have a add and delete feature.

```
using System;

struct ItemData
{
    public int ItemNumber;
    public string Description;
    public double PricePerItem;
    public int QuantityOnHand;
    public double OurCostPerItem;
    public double ValueOfItem;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int invItems = 0;
        var items = new ItemData[10];


        while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("1. Add, 2. Change, 3. Delete, 4. List:");
            string strx = Console.ReadLine();
            var choice = int.Parse(strx);

            Console.WriteLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
```

This is what I have so far but not sure where to start

```
case 2: //change items
                    {
                        Console.Write("Please enter an item ID No:");
                        string input = Console.ReadLine();
                        int changeItemNumber = int.Parse(input);
                        bool foundItem = false;

                        for (int x = 0; x < invItems; x++)
                        {
                            if (items[x].ItemNumber == changeItemNumber)
                            {

                             //code   
                           
                            }
                        }

                        if (!foundItem)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Item {0} not found", changeItemNumber);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: There is not enough information provided to give you a correct answer... what is items, invItems ? have you tried using the Linq to find the item you want to update, `items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemNumber == changeItemNumber)`. Once you have the item, update the fields and use `.SaveChanges()` method (if you are using EF).

Comment: Welcome here, it is really a pleasure to help you but please provide as much as you can details with data examples so the reader can understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: You can edit your post and provide more details, please also have a tour about the usage of the platform using https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @U8080 Ok I edited the first part with the whole top of my code

Comment: Please share the `//code` code with us.

Comment: `fFound` - name that `foundItem` instead.

Comment: the //code is what I need help with making

Comment: I afraid your code is not enough to help and I assume you are a very beginner in the database, so I will post an answer to help you to start. Wait for me for an answer within some minutes

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little unclear what you're asking so if this is wide of the mark then feel free to let me know.

Start by mapping out the flow of the process and then implement one piece at a time. Here's a basic series of operations you'll want to do, not necessarily in this order:

- Input `ItemNumber`.
- Find index of matching record in array.

  - If not found report error and stop.
- Get record from user.
- Set `ItemNumber` in record to entered value.
- Store record in array at same index as original.

If you think about the way the rest of the program works you should see that some of those parts - maybe most of them - are already done somewhere in your code. Your `add` operation probably already has the `Get record from user` code. Your `delete` operation probably has `Input ItemNumber` and `Find index of matching record in array` done already.

So pull those parts out into methods and reuse them where it makes sense. Anywhere you're writing the same code multiple times with minor changes try to see if you can extract the code into a small method you can call with maybe some parameters. Your "input a number" code for instance - used for operation selection, item number entry and presumably whatever you're doing for delete - can be pulled out to a supporting method like this one:

```
static int InputNumber(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
    var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
    return int.Parse(inputText);
}
```

Now when you want to change the way you're doing number input you have a central place to make the changes and you don't have to worry about tracking down all the places you wrote the same code.

The same goes for the rest of the pieces. When two operations share some of the same code then pull that code out to supporting methods. Finding the index of an item in the array by some criteria can - and should - be one of those:

```
// Return array index of matching item or -1 if not found
int ItemIndex(int itemNumber)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < invItems; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].ItemNumber == itemNumber)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Likewise the code - whatever that looks like - that your `add` operation uses to get a record from the user.

Once you do that your `change item` case looks a lot simpler:

```
case 2: // change items
    var itemNumber = InputNumber("Please enter an item ID");
    var index = ItemIndex(itemNumber);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item {itemNumber} not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        var newItem = InputItemData();
        newItem.ItemNumber = itemNumber;
        items[index] = newItem;
    }
    break;
```

For bonus points you can actually provide the current values to the `InputItemData` method so the user can re-use them instead of just asking for a complete new record each time.